# Closed question appeal

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

I am protesting the closing of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733320/managed-modules-what-are-they).

This should absolutely not be closed as "off topic". "A module is an ASP.Net component that plugs in to some point of the request pipeline;" if that doesn't relate to programming then I'm not sure what does. A programmer ABSOLUTELY NEEDS to understand what he's calling and what he's referencing even if it's a few layers of abstraction away. Changes to the web.config are most certainly something a web programmer would do on a regular basis.

To write an application and not care to understand what's happening to make your code work is careless and lazy. I ask that this question not be closed for those reasons.

Aside from all that, there are over 4,000 web config questions on stack overflow the vast majority of which are not closed...

From the FAQ for closed questions

> What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people
>   who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow
>   questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question
>   generally covers …
>
> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - **software tools commonly used by programmers**
> - **practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming    profession**
>
> **… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!**

Edit:Thank you everyone I appreciate the guidance and help.

Comment: yay for downvotes. Downvote someone who asks to have a closed question appealed when they read on meta stack overflow that they can come here to have a closed question appealed.

Comment: @Preston: [Voting is different on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq). As for Andrew Barber's edit, it was to move the meta discussion from your original question to here, where it belongs.

Comment: umm. ok didn't know there was an official format or anything... thank you.

Comment: I didn't think it was off topic, and I've voted to reopen. 4 other people will need to do so for the question to be reopened.

Comment: Just threw my reopen vote back into the ring.  It might be a *basic* question, but it's well-formulated and the answer is worthy.  That said, I do tend to like closing excessively basic questions as NARQ.  Closing them as off-topic is silly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, closing this is off-topic seems weird to me. I can see how it could, perhaps, be a basic question or something that's obvious to more experienced folks, but *off-topic*? I don't buy that.

I'd like to see a few more opinions voiced here (especially pro-closing, just in case I'm missing something) before taking action, but at the moment I'm inclined to reopen the question.

Comment: I happen to agree; I think off topic isn't necessarily the proper closing reason, assuming the question needed to be closed. I could see "Not a Real Question". I, too, would like to see some feedback on why "Off Topic".

Comment: May I ask why people seem to be so heavy on the close question trigger finger? Is it a band wagon mentality or what?

Comment: @Preston In my experience people vote to close with the best intentions - they are trying to keep the site free of questions that do not belong on Stack Overflow. Don't take it personally. Mistakes happen sometimes, but they can be reversed easily enough, especially if we focus on the question and not on trying to assign blame or malice.

Comment: I understand that but I can remember a number of times where I have been helped by a question that was "closed" but still had an answer. It just seems strange that it happens in some cases.

Comment: @Preston That's the price we pay for community-driven moderation. Sometimes there are ... deviations. (Or the question really did need to be closed and the fact that it turned out to be helpful as well as off-topic is a happy accident.) My point is that the motivation behind closures ultimately comes from the right place, even if it sometimes comes across negatively. We're currently looking at making some improvements to the close system to hopefully mitigate the negative experiences.

Comment: @Preston If I were you, I would pay special attention to this statement Anna Lear made here in the comments: "*Mistakes happen sometimes, but they can be reversed easily enough, especially if we* ***focus on the question and not on trying to assign blame or malice.***"  Just try to be careful of your tone when asking questions like this here on Meta.  People generally have good intentions around here =)

Answer (score 4):

Peston says in the post that he's a sysadmin, and deploying something to a server or getting something to run on a server is something that a sysadmin might do. For instance, I'm sure the Stack Exchange System Administrators have to have considerable knowledge of IIS and how to get .NET stuff to run on it.

At the same time, being a .NET developer, one must also have knowledge of the platform that the code will run on; thus, instead of being off-topic, this seems like one of those questions that, depending on how it's tailored, could exist on either Stack Overflow or Server Fault. I don't see it as being something that is off-topic here, and I would vote to reopen.

Comment: agreed, I am a sys admin and that is kind of where this is coming from but I am also studying software engineering and have been doing a lot of .NET lately so I threw in knowledge and terminology from both worlds I guess.

Comment: My advice would be, since you have knowledge of both the engineering and system admin sides, is to take into consideration your audience when posting questions on Stack Exchange. For instance, even though your question might be on topic on Server Fault, I'd suggest using more language that a Sysadmin would be more familiar with in order to help avoid confusion, but on Stack Overflow, focus more on how it's a programming/developer issue. Good luck with your problem and solution! :)

Comment: @Preston Even though I did vote to reopen your question referenced here (something I almost never do!), I also agree with the advice here, and that it could apply to this question as well.

Comment: @AndrewBarber You should do it more often there are an awful lot of questions out there like mine that are closed (often by the same gang of users) that could be beneficial to many people. And honestly once a question is closed it does no good fixing it... it's gone never to be looked at again. (unless you do something like this) It's very frustrating to new users.

Comment: @Preston I review the reopen queue constantly. I vote to keep almost every single one closed.